# Any way to cancel a request in SSMS?

Tags: ssms

I say cancel a "request" rather than a query because typically I am able to continue using Management Studio when I am running queries. However, I have remote access to an Azure database that shuts off after an hour of no activity. When I send it a query and it's shut down, it take a really long time to fire up and I'm not able to continue working during this time as Management Studio completely freezes.

I am literally still waiting on the request that prompted me to write this post to complete and it has been several minutes now. In this case, I actually ran my query on the wrong connection and did not even mean to hit the Azure database so it's especially annoying that I have to wait this long, lol.

If I didn't know better I would think it was permanently locked, but this has happened enough times now that I know it will eventually return control.

Comment: You can *cancel* a running query with  `Alt`+`Break`. If SSMS isn't responding, however, which appear to be what you are saying, that's totally different. You end a task that isn't responding in Task Manager or in your CLI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By your description, you have a SERVERLESS  version of Azure SQL Database.

When this shuts off the compute due to lack of activity, it completely removes the compute portion of the service - simply leaving your database on storage. When you then query it again for the first time, it needs to allocate some compute to the database, start that up (with the redundant copies that Azure SQL provides), connect to your database, ensure the gateway is up to date to direct your connection and only THEN will it accept a connection.

So, with Management Studio, it is waiting on the response and I believe that it also has some degree of retry so that it keeps checking until the connection is established.

You could change the tier to a PROVISIONED service tier where it is available all the time (your billing will change so be sure it is what you need) and this will stop, or you could have a PowerShell script or similar that you run to ensure the database is available before connecting from SSMS.

When it is waiting for the response back from the service that it has started OK, there isn't a session available to `KILL` - so your only scope there would be to kill the client - i.e. use task manager to shut down SSMS.

Comment: Thanks, we've decided to move away from Azure altogether so problem solved. :)